# Best free richtextbox for ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, richtextbox

What is the best rich text box to use with ASP.NET 2.0?

I need to allow users (non technical) format their own email with simply styling, but it needs to be shown as they type, rather than a markup language with a preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no problems with http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ and has some nice features too. it's written in javascript as is http://www.fckeditor.net/

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com works in chrome

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work with Update Panels. ;( 

http://weblogs.asp.net/cjdevos/archive/2008/03/03/ajax-extender-for-tinymce-including-fix-for-updatepanels.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/p/1034078/1584748.aspx

Comment: Correction - Moxiecode is the one that has trouble with Update Panels. We are working with FCKEditor now... which seems great so far. Thank you.

Comment: yeah fckeditor is awesome, i've used it in several projects

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://freetextbox.com/

My only complaint is that is doesn't work (but degrades gracefully) in Chrome.  I expect a fix for that sometime soon, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would throw my vote in for

http://www.fckeditor.net/

Despite it's 'almost naughty' name it's a great rich text box and very easy to use.

Comment: Ah, that name. There was one (almost career-ending) incident when I suggested we use it for a project and someone read through the name.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/), and it seems pretty good so far.